# Angular - Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HomeComponent: (?, ?, ?, ?)

Tags: angular, typescript

While running the angular project it comes with the error

> Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HomeComponent: (?, ?,
>   ?, ?).

`HomeComponent` have four services called. All services are made `Injectable`. When all the services are removed from constructor runs fine but adding these services causes problems.

**HomeComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PashminaModel } from '../../model/pashmina.model';
import { HomeService } from '../../services/home-service/home-service';
import { Category } from "../../enum/Enum";
import { FooterService } from "../../services/footer/footer.service";
import { NavbarService } from "../../services/navbar/navbar.service";
import { DataService } from '../../services/data-service/data.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
constructor(
        private homeService: HomeService,
        private navService: NavbarService,
        private footerService: FooterService,
        private data: DataService
    ) {
}

------
-------
```

This is how I have implemented a provider section in `app.module.ts`

```
providers: [
        AuthorizationComponent,
        NavbarService,
        FooterService,
        LoginServiceEndpoint,
        LoginService,
        PashminaServiceEndpoint,
        PashminaService,
        ImageServiceEndpoint,
        ImageService,
        DescriptionServiceEndpoint,
        DescriptionService,
        ColorServiceEndpoint,
        ColorService,
        HomeService,
        HomeServiceEndpoint,
        AccountService,
        AccountServiceEndpoint,
        OrderServiceEndpoint,
        OrderService,
        DataService
    ],
```

Before it was working fine but suddenly appears this error.

Comment: Are all those object you injected in the ctor  , in the providers section in app.module ?

Comment: @Eris- It seems fine in provider section. Can you tell me what might cause this

Comment: Can you paste the providers section ?

Comment: @Eris - I have pasted a provider section please have a look

Comment: are you using services in your services ? could it be you're missing `@Injectable()` decorator on one of your services ?

Comment: @Stavm - All the services are provided with `@Injectable()`

Comment: add services to your constructor one by one to pinpoint the problematic one. when pinpointed, please place its code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `pollyfills.ts`, you should have commented these two lines:

```
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

Uncomment this. It should work flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

You have added **`AuthorizationComponent`** inside the providers, remove all the components from providers and add them under **`declarations`**

```
providers: [
        AuthorizationComponent,  //remove from here and add under declarations
        NavbarService,
        FooterService,
        LoginServiceEndpoint,
        LoginService,
        PashminaServiceEndpoint,
        PashminaService,
        ImageServiceEndpoint,
        ImageService,
        DescriptionServiceEndpoint,
        DescriptionService,
        ColorServiceEndpoint,
        ColorService,
        HomeService,
        HomeServiceEndpoint,
        AccountService,
        AccountServiceEndpoint,
        OrderServiceEndpoint,
        OrderService,
        DataService
 ]
```

Comment: hawkeye. plus one.

Comment: I have made `AuthorizationComponent` as a `Injectable`

Comment: It was working before even `AuthorizationComponent` is on `provider` section

Comment: a component should not be "provided". sajeetharan post's down vote is not appropriate.

Comment: @Stavm - `AuthorizationComponent` is not a component I made it as a `@Injectable`. Sorry for the incorrect name and I didn't downvote the @Sajeetharan answer